# PHP removing text in a link

Tags: php, string, forms

How do you strip/remove wording in PHP?

I have a form that's passing a full URL link to an output page.

Example:
maps/africa.pdf

And on the output page, I want to provide an "href link", but in PHP use that same posted URL, but strip off the "maps" and have it provide a link that just says africa.

Example:
africa

can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Use [`pathinfo`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$filename = 'maps/africa.pdf';
$title = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

If you want only `.pdf` to be stripped, use [`basename`](http://us.php.net/basename):

```
$filename = 'maps/africa.pdf';
$title = basename($filename, '.pdf');
```

Comment: duh, of course... this is a much simpler solution than using a regex. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'maps/africa.pdf';

$link_title = str_replace(array('maps/', '.pdf'), '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you just want the file name? If so, then that would be everything between the last slash and the last dot.

```
if (preg_match("@/([^/]+)\\.[^\\./]+$@", $href, $matches)) {
    $linkText = $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers here. Also, if you know the url every time you could count the characters and use **substr()** e.g. https://www.php.net/substr

`$rest = substr("abcdef", 2, -1);  // returns "cde"`